# Duplicated key error after the first create with discriminator in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a base schema and a derived one in mongoose. If i start with a fresh db and I create the first base document, everything is ok. However the second creation is never succeed with warning code:

> (node:7584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: somedb.base index: name_1 dup key: { : null }

Despite that, I can crate any number of derived documents.
If I remove the discriminator part, and store the base and derived in different collection than everything is ok. So i think something is wrong with the way I inherited the model.

base.js

```
var db = require('../config/db');

var Schema = db.Schema;

var baseSchema = new Schema({
    lat: {
        type: Schema.Types.Number,
        required: true
    },
    lon: {
        type: Schema.Types.Number,
        required: true
    }
}, {discriminatorKey: 'kind'})

var Base = db.model('base', baseSchema);

module.exports = Base;
```

derived.js

```
var db = require('../config/db');

var Schema = db.Schema;

var derivedSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: Schema.Types.String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    type: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'base',
        required: true
    }
}, {discriminatorKey: 'kind'})

var Base = db.model("base");

var Derived = Base.discriminator('derived', derivedSchema);

module.exports = Derived;
```

**Update**

The duplicate key error is because in the derived model, name is unique. When I inserted base documents, name was always null, and that's why it's duplicated. However I want the name to be unique but only if its a derived document. How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago. I searched for a few answers and came across [sparse indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/) that can be applied for this specific problem. However, since mongoose now supports something called [partial indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/), it should be preferred over a sparse index:

> Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, MongoDB provides the
>   option to create **partial indexes**. Partial indexes **offer a superset** **of**
>   **the functionality of sparse indexes**. If you are using MongoDB 3.2 or
>   later, **partial indexes should be preferred** over sparse indexes.

If you are using Mongoose +4.6.1 you can apply an index directly on the scheme:

```
baseSchema.index({name: 1}, {unique: true, partialFilterExpression: {kind: {$eq: 'derived'}}});
```

If you are using an older version, you have to create the index by using the native driver:

```
db.collection('baseSchema').createIndex({ name: 1 }, {
    unique: true,
    partialFilterExpression: {
      kind: { $eq: 'derived' }
    }
  });
```